# mysql union getting 2 column names from another table corresponding to 2 id columns

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have a table "task" which stores the details of a task that is created, I need to get the names of the creator ID and the ASSIGNEDTO ID in a single query for which i created a UNION however I get the following error in mysql

Both the select queries execute perfectly as individual queries

`#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

```
SELECT a.task_id, a.task_title,a.task_created_by,a.task_creation_date,b.user_id, b.user_email  FROM task a,users b WHERE a.task_created_by = b.user_id

UNION

SELECT a.task_assigned_to, b.user_email FROM task a,users b WHERE a.task_assigned_to = b.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Only selects based on same columns can be subjects to UNION
2. There's a workaround that implies using "as" for any column that you might not have in the other table. Like this:

`SELECT b, '' as c FROM table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT b, c FROM table2`

Based on this the "c" for table1 will always be empty, but the UNION will still work.

Use this logic to UNION tables that have different columns